# Cannot compile new QuickFix version in C++20

Tags: c++, quickfix

I have worked with a older version of QuickFix. Now I have updated my code to C++20 and installed the newest version of QuickFix. I have downloaded the code from https://github.com/quickfix/quickfix.
Now I get compiler errors:
FIX::FieldBase" has no member "first"
FIX::FieldBase" has no member "second"

This is the code that works with the old version of QuickFix, but not with the actual version:

```
const FIX::FieldMap& fieldMap
...
for (auto itr = fieldMap.begin(), end = fieldMap.end(); itr != end; ++itr)
{
    if (itr->second.getLength())
    {
        ...
    }
}   
...
```

The problem is the following line in FieldMap.h:

```
typedef std::vector < FieldBase, ALLOCATOR< FieldBase > > Fields;
```

This the a except from the old version:

```
typedef std::multimap < int, FieldBase, message_order, ALLOCATOR<std::pair<const int,FieldBase> > > Fields;
```

It seems that multimap is replaced by a vector. Can anybody give an advice?

Comment: maps are slow. vectors are more efficient in most cases...

Answer (score 1):

The map from `int` to `FieldBase` has been replaced by a `vector<FieldBase>`, which is in some sense a map from `int` (index) to `FieldBase` too.

Just replace

`itr->second.getLength();`

with

```
itr->getLength();
```

Depending on the context you might be able to replace the loop with a simpler range-based for-loop which does not mention iterators:

```
for (const FieldBase &fb : fieldMap) {
    fb.getLength();
}
```

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much. I have one further question. What about this code? dataDictionary->getFieldName(itr->first, fieldName);